# asp.net core redirect http traffic to https issue

Tags: ssl, https, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-middleware

I have just installed an ssl certificate on my host, and thought I would redirect all http traffic to https.  I found that there is a new package for helping with it in .net core.

The problem is that it doesn't work for me and I can't figure out why.  When I try to navigate to http://mysite.co.uk to test the redirection it fails with a message saying

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>   Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
>   This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Here is my stratup.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Playabout.Data;
using Playabout.Models;
using Playabout.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Globalization;
using Sakura.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;
using System.Net;

namespace Playabout
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false,     reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json",     optional: true);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
            //builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
        }

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(
            config =>
            {
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>
            (options => options.Level = CompressionLevel.Optimal);
            services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
            {
                options.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(new[]
                {
                    "text/plain",
                    "text/css",
                    "application/javascript",
                    "text/html",
                    "application/xml",
                    "text/xml",
                    "application/json",
                    "text/json",
                    // Custom
                    "text/javascript",
                    "image/svg+xml"
                });
                options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
            });

        services.AddMvc();


        // Add application services.
        services.Configure<SmtpConfig>(optionsSetup =>
        {
            //get from config.json file
            optionsSetup.EmailDisplayName = Configuration["SMTP:DisplayName"];
            optionsSetup.SmtpPassworrd = Configuration["SMTP:Password"];
            optionsSetup.SmtpUserEmail = Configuration["SMTP:Email"];
            optionsSetup.SmtpHost = Configuration["SMTP:Host"];
            optionsSetup.SmtpPort = Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["SMTP:Port"]);
        });
        services.Configure<RecaptchaConfig>(optionsSetup =>
        {
            //get from config.json file
            optionsSetup.RecaptchaPublicKey = Configuration["Recaptcha:PublicKey"];
            optionsSetup.RecaptchaPrivateKey = Configuration["Recaptcha:PrivateKey"];
        });
        // Add default bootstrap-styled pager implementation
        services.AddBootstrapPagerGenerator(options =>
        {
            // Use default pager options.
            options.ConfigureDefault();
        });
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddSession();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-GB"),

        };
        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB"),
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        });
        app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRedirectToHttps());
        app.UseResponseCompression();
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
            {
                const int durationInSeconds = 60 * 60 * 730;
                ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
                    "public,max-age=" + durationInSeconds;
            }
        });

        app.UseSession();
        app.UseIdentity();

        // Add external authentication middleware below. To configure them please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions()
        {
            AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"],
            AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"]
        });
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions()
        {
            ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"],
            ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"]
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        try
        {
            await CreateRoles(context, serviceProvider);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
    }
    private async Task CreateRoles(ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        // Create a list of roles with both name and normalised name attributes
        List<IdentityRole> roles = new List<IdentityRole>
        {
            new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin", NormalizedName = "ADMIN" },
            new IdentityRole { Name = "Member", NormalizedName = "MEMBER" },
            new IdentityRole { Name = "Moderator", NormalizedName = "MODERATOR" }
        };
        // Check if the role already exists
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role.Name);
            if (!roleExist)
            {   // Add it if it doesn't
                context.Roles.Add(role);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync("markperry.uk@gmail.com");
        if (user != null)
        {
            var gotRoles = userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            if (!gotRoles.Equals("Admin"))
            {
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
            }
        }
        else if (user == null)
        {
            var nuser = new ApplicationUser
            {
                FirstName = Configuration["AppSettings:Admin:FirstName"],
                LastName = Configuration["AppSettings:Admin:LastName"],
                PhoneNumber = Configuration["AppSettings:Admin:PhoneNumber"],
                UserName = Configuration["AppSettings:Admin:UserName"],
                Email = Configuration["AppSettings:Admin:Email"],
                JoinDate = DateTime.Now,
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = true
            };
            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(nuser, Configuration["AppSettings:Admin:Password"]);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await userManager.AddClaimAsync(nuser, new Claim("GivenName", nuser.FirstName));
                await userManager.AddClaimAsync(nuser, new Claim("Surname", nuser.LastName));
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(nuser, "Admin");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The snippet I added to configure is:

```
        app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
        .AddRedirectToHttps());
```

which uses Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;

I have just used chrome to inspect, and that shows repeated redirects, and fails due to "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" so something is causing a loop.

Is there a way to check if the request is already "https", or is there another way I can do things?

Answer (score 1):

After spending the whole day trying to sort this out, adding [RequireHttps] attributes, trying a variety of snippets I found googling the issue, trying to pass headers... In the end I resorted to something I tried earlier that hadn't seemed to have worked.  I edited the web.config file that is on the server (I don't know how to do it at publish) adding the following:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP/S to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="^0$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Taken from a comment here: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/916

From what I've read, its to do with Kestrel, I'm not entirely sure what though :D but it works! It's going to be annoying to have to change this every publish, so tomorrow I'll try and figure out how this can be done for me each time.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve a similar issue with the following:

```
if (env.IsProduction())
{
    app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent());
}
```

Comment: I got hopefull there :) but sadly, it still has the same error.  It's redirecting, which is something I suppose, but there's something I'm missing somewhere.